# PHP - Telnet to arduino, run commands and get output

Tags: php, arduino, telnet

I am making an arduino web controlled thermostat. My arduino is running a telnet server, and I am trying to use PHP to send telnet commands to the arduino. However, the PHP telnet always says connection refused. It works via command line though

PHP:

telnet class: https://github.com/spaceapps-stuttgart/NASA-Planetary-Data-System-Interface/blob/master/php-telnet/telnet.class.php

```
<?php
require_once 'telnet.class.php';

$status = '';
$telnet = new Telnet();


if(!$telnet->connect())
{
echo "failed to connect";
}
$telnet->exec('set30');
$telnet->exec('quit');
?>
```

Arduino code:

http://pastebin.com/zX9M0ur3

Comment: Have you tried connecting via the actual `telnet` command on your terminal? Did it work?

Comment: yes, that works perfectly. Only when I try to telnet via PHP it does not work

Comment: could you edit your question to reflect what you tried on the command line?